# cross compile paho.mqtt.c for imx6ull (32 bit arm)

Tags: c, mqtt, cross-compiling

I have code which publish to aws using paho.mqtt.c library. I can compile and run it in my laptop running linux.

```
bhagwat@bhagwat:~/bhagwatws/mqtt/MQTT$ gcc publish.c -o pub -lpaho-mqtt3cs
bhagwat@bhagwat:~/bhagwatws/mqtt/MQTT$ ./pub 
Waiting for up to 10 seconds for publication of Hello Duniya!
on topic MQTT Examples for client with ClientID: ExampleClientPub
Message with delivery token 1 delivered
bhagwat@bhagwat:~/bhagwatws/mqtt/MQTT$
```

I have cross compiler installed. When I try to cross compile the code it show the error as  follows

```
bhagwat@bhagwat:~/bhagwatws/mqtt/MQTT$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc publish.c -o pub -lpaho-mqtt3cs
publish.c:4:10: fatal error: MQTTClient.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include "MQTTClient.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

my publish code include the MQTTClient.h header.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"
```

Can anyone guide me how to cross compile the code

Comment: Where is the `MQTTClient.h` file actually located relative to the `publish.c` file?

Comment: @hardillb  path to publish.c  is /home/bhagwat/bhagwatws/mqtt/MQTT/publish.c  and path to MQTTClient.h   is  /home/bhagwat/bhagwatws/mqtt/paho.mqtt.c/src/MQTTCleint.h

Comment: Are you sure that it's using the `/home/bhagwat/bhagwatws/mqtt/paho.mqtt.c/src/MQTTCleint.h` copy? Much more likely it's using a copy from somewhere like `/usr/local/include` if you have run `make install` in the paho client dir.  I expect you need to cross-compile (and install with the right pre-fix, the paho library as well)

Comment: @hardillb Can I get some help about how to cross compile paho.mqtt.c library for arm platform